# How to add user to ALL Google Analytics accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, bulk, user-permissions

I need to add a user with permissions to all 620 Analytics accounts that I have access to with my main Google account. I am trying to add an e-mail of the type something@developer.gserviceaccount.com to all these accounts so that I can edit and manage them through the Google Analytics API.

I'm talking about these kinds of permissions:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495?hl=en

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en

Looking at [this article](http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/get-the-most-out-of-google-analytics-user-permissions/), they say that you can delegate permissions at these levels:

[image]

The problem is that I have 620 accounts!

Comment: Figured it out! Instead of a "Service account" as I previously created, now I created an "Installed application" credential. This one opens up a browser window that asks me to authenticate, and then can access all Analytics accounts that my Google user has access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Instead of a "Service account" as I previously created, now I created an "Installed application" credential. This one opens up a browser window that asks me to authenticate, and then can access all Analytics accounts that my Google user has access to. Like this:
[image]

Comment: I have to assume this is not a correct solution for the problem you described. The application type is based on whether you are working with a website, an automated service, or a desktop app. It has nothing to do with how permissions are granted for different properties. I am currently looking for a solution to exactly the question that you asked, but there seems to not be one.

Comment: @sfarbota, any luck? :-)

Comment: Hah, it's been a while but I don't think I ever found a great solution for this. One thing that comes to mind now is the possibility of creating a group and giving that group access to all accounts (assuming that is possible). You'd only have to do that work once, then all future users could in theory just be added to the one group. Feel free to test that out and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The Management API allows you to programmatically add users. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions

Edit: As noted in comments (thanks, @EikePierstorff), there is an upper limit of 100 accounts that can be added per user.

Comment: The problem is that to be able to programmatically add users I need to already have an existing user that has rights to manage accounts and users. As the article you mentioned says: *These operations can only be performed by users that have MANAGE_USERS level permissions*. Well that was my initial question: how do I add such a user to all the accounts?

Comment: This is a bit difficult to parse - as it stands you are saying that you want to add users despite not having permissions to do so, which is of course impossible (that's kind of the point with permissions). Can we assume that at least your "main Google Account" has proper permissions ?  In any case the API won't work for you, as the docs specifially state "There is an upper bound of 100 accounts per user for the API"(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions).

Comment: I have a google account in the form of **mcb999@gmail.com**, that has access to all of these Analytics accounts: http://content.screencast.com/users/CostinPopescu/folders/Default/media/c8ca82fe-5e9c-4192-a99c-d33ec1119505/analytics%20accounts.png However, when I add a new credential for the Google API project, I get a generated e-mail in the form of **76972394287234-ajdsnkjsadnaskjnkjfa@developer.gserviceaccount.com**. I can authenticate my console app using that e-mail, but I cannot seem to be able to use my main e-mail, mcb999@gmail.com.

Comment: So while the main e-mail has all permissions for all accounts, the generated one has no permissions, so I would have to go through each account and add the new e-mail with permissions.

Comment: Figured it out! Instead of a "Service account" as I previously created, now I created an "Installed application" credential. This one opens up a browser window that asks me to authenticate, and then can access all Analytics accounts that my Google user has access to.